# Changing style in OpenLayers clustered features

Tags: json, mapping, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers with Javascript and showing clustered features on map. I would like to change the icon of the feature within a cluster according to one of its attributes value.

```
var style1 = new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 66],anchorXUnits: 'fraction',anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.85,src: 'https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/home.png',scale: 0.3
      }));
      var style2 = new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 66],anchorXUnits: 'fraction',anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.85,src: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/summer.png',scale: 0.3
      }));
      function myStyleFunction(feature) {
        let props = feature.getProperties();
        if (props.id>50) {
          console.log(props.id);
          return new ol.style.Style({image: style1,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
        } else {
          console.log(props.id);
          return new ol.style.Style({image: style2,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
        }
      };
```

In the code above, i want to access the property "id" of one of the features within the cluster and set its icon based on the "id" value. However, I can't get the feature property.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/agristatseu/pen/rRorBR). I would appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only check the first feature in each cluster:

```
  function myStyleFunction(feature) {
    let props = feature.get('features')[0].getProperties();
    if (props.id>50) {
      console.log(props.id);
      return new ol.style.Style({image: style1,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
    } else {
      console.log(props.id);
      return new ol.style.Style({image: style2,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
    }
  };
```

If you want to find the value in any feature in the cluster

```
  function myStyleFunction(feature) {
    let maxId = 0;
    feature.get('features').forEach(function(feature){
      maxId = Math.max(maxId, feature.getProperties().id);
    });
    if (maxId>50) {
      console.log(maxId);
      return new ol.style.Style({image: style1,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
    } else {
      console.log(maxId);
      return new ol.style.Style({image: style2,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
    }
  };
```

For an ol-ext cluster

```
  function myStyleFunction(feature) {
    let id = 0;
    let features = feature.get('features');
    if (features) {
      id = features[0].get('id');
    }
    if (id > 50) {
      return new ol.style.Style({image: style1,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
    } else {
      return new ol.style.Style({image: style2,stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color:"#fff", width:1 }) });
    }
  };
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and none of them changes the style of any feature within the cluster. Let me repeat the need: according to the "id" property value of each feature the feature itself must take the respective style. For example, if the cluster has two features with<50 and two features with id>50, there must be two features with style1 and two features with style2.

Comment: If you want to show individual features it's not a cluster.  Or did you want to show separate cluster counts for features greater and less than 50?  Then you would need two cluster layers.

Comment: The codepen in my question shows that by clicking on the cluster it expands and all separate features are shown. I need them to be shown with a respective icon.

Comment: The ol-ext cluster layer works differently to a normal OpenLayers cluster, The style function is called once for each original feature with that feature as the sole entry the features array.  It's also called with no features array, which caused an error with my first method.

Comment: This is it, it works perfectly! I didn't realize that ol-ext was different regarding cluster layers. Thank you very much!